# Is my derived PDE linear?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I am trying to decide whether my derived PDE is linear - I am drawing a blank. If someone could demonstrate why it is/isn't that would be great! I have used the MHD equations of motion and induction in cylindrical polars to dervie the following. We assume that $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\theta}=0$.

$\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial v_z}{\partial z}+v_z\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)W_\theta=\dfrac{1}{\mu}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}(B_\theta B_z v_\theta)-\dfrac{B_\theta^2}{2\mu}\dfrac{\partial  v_z}{\partial z}$

I have that $W_\theta=\dfrac{v_\theta^2 \rho}{2}+\dfrac{B_\theta^2}{2}$ is the energy density,
B is the magnetic field in three dimensions 
v is the velocity in three dimensions. All of the components only comprise of Z as I have used the definition for the area of a coronal hole ($A(z)=az^n$ for n=2) - this allows us to represent the plasma (solar wind) moving with a coronal hole.

Comment: No it is not - you have products of terms such as $B_\theta B_z v_\theta$. So it is non-linear

Comment: It seems to be a Navier-Stokes-like equation (perhaps N-S itself, I'm not used to it in cylindrical coordinates). Could you clarify what is the independent variable? Is it $W_\theta$? What are $B_z$ and $B_\theta$? Are these also independent variables?

Comment: @rafa11111 I have edited it to show that $W_\theta$ is dependent on $B_\theta$. It is related to N-S, I am modelling how the Solar Wind traverses through a coronal hole in this insntance.

Comment: @KieranSQ It is some sort of momentum transport equation, isn't it? Therefore, your independent variables are $v_\theta$ and $v_z$, I suppose. Then, the equation is non-linear (just like the N-S itself) because of $v_\theta^2$ in $W_\theta$ and $v_z$ in the convective term. Remember that N-S is non-linear for the same reason; it is a equation of transport of 'velocity', and the it's the velocity itself that transport stuff (it was quite imprecise, but that's the idea). If you found this satisfactory, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @rafa11111 yes it is a momentum transport equation. Yes your explanation makes a lot of sense and is clear when you consider what $W_\theta$ comprises of and the N-S equations. Thank you for clarifying, it was a great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation seems to be a particular case of the [Cauchy momentum equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_momentum_equation):
$$
\rho \left(\frac{\partial \mathbf{v}}{\partial t} + \mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{v} \right)= \nabla \cdot \mathbf{\sigma} + \mathbf{g}
$$
in which $\sigma$ is the stress tensor (involving pressure and viscosity) and $\bf{g}$ is the body force (gravitation, magnetism, etc.). In this form, even in the absence of any term in RHS, the equation is non-linear, due to the $\bf{v} \cdot \nabla \bf{v}$.

It don't make *that* sense to talk about independent variables without proper context; in three dimensions (the most general case) this (vectorial) equation are actually three (scalar) equations, and there is four (or even five) variables: the three components of $\bf{v}$ and the pressure, that is hidden inside $\sigma$ (and, eventually, $\rho$, if your flow is compressible). You need also a mass conservation equation and a equation of state (and even an energy conservation equation, if this process is relevant).

Another source of non-linearity can be inside $\sigma$ if the viscous stress tensor is not Newtonian. In the most general case, each component of a Newtonian stress tensor is a *linear* combination of gradients of the velocity components. Any other viscous behavior is necessarily non-linear.

Returning, finally, to your case, the sources of non-linearity are the convective term $v_z \frac{\partial W_\theta}{\partial z}$ and the definition of $W_\theta$ itself. The first one is the same intrinsic non-linearity of Cauchy momentum equation and of the well-known Navier Stokes equation.

Answer (score 1):

The PDE is linear in each of $v_z$, $v_\theta$, $B_z$ and $W_\theta$ separately, but not in $B_\theta$ (because of the square in the last term).

Even if the last term were skipped, it wouldn't be linear in $B = (B_\theta, B_z)$ because of the product $B_\theta B_z$ in the next last term.